# Facebook "Like" request parameters absent

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a like button. We populate the data-href with something like: http://foo.com/stuff/1?tracking=member1

When facebook scrapes our page for the title and images defined in the "og" meta tags, it disregards the original request parameters from the data-href. This means we can't customize the title and image based on the referring member, but this is exactly what we need to do.

We have tried all sorts of combinations of values for the data-href and og:url fields to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

within the head tags:

```
<meta content="This title should be based on the referring member" property="og:title"></meta>
<meta content="Content would go here" property="og:description"></meta>
<meta content="http://foo.com/stuff/1" property="og:url"></meta>
<meta content="http://foo.com/images/hello.png" property="og:image"></meta>
<meta content="Foolandia" property="og:site_name"></meta>
```

and then our like button tag:

```
<fb:like data-action="like" data-href="http://foo.com/stuff/1" data-ref="member1" data-send="false" data-show-faces="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

So, after several permutations and combinations, this is how we were able to address this issue:

We added the member id to the data-href (http://foo.com/stuff/1?tracking=member1) and removed the og:url from our meta-tags. Facebook now scrapes our page with the url: http://foo.com/stuff/1?tracking=member1 and we're able to customize the title and image displayed on facebook based on the referring member.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value for `og:url` tag your URL is returning to the Facebook crawler is the same one in the `data-href`? facebook will, if it finds a canonical meta tag or og:url tag on the scraped page, discard the metadata and retrieve metadata from the canonical URL instead.

You can test what facebook detects for a URL with [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: In fact we're sure it's **not** the same value. The request param is essentially the member id. When FB scrapes, it isn't the referring member. We'd like to make FB use the data-href url with the request params, since when we build that url we know who the member is. When FB comes back to scrape on a separate request, we've lost that info. We thought maybe omitting the og:url would cause FB to rely instead on the data-href, but it still understands the canonical url as foo.com/stuff/1. How do we force FB to consider the data-href to be canonical?

Comment: You don't, the `og:url` tag on a piece of content is where the canonical metadata for that page is supposed to live - the crawler goes there instead - you could redirect other browsers than land on those pages, but the crawler needs to get consistent metadata